# Calculate a margin using CSS percentage and unit together

Tags: css, dimension

```
margin-left: 100 + 20%;
```

I want to do something the same as above. But CSS does not have any format. How can I successfully use these together ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without javascript? Only by wrapping that content into another element (usually `<div>`) and splitting that margin to two elements.

Something like:

```
<div style="margin-left:20%">
  <div style="margin-left:100px">
  <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is really good ! but does it really work? also the division inside will have a margin at 100 px to the out division ?thanks !

Comment: You will have to try it. But I don't see why it shouldn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately CSS doesn't have this (good) behaviour, but LESS will. For a JavaScript implementation, look [here](http://lesscss.org/). If you want a PHP implementation, look [here](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/). You may be confused as to why I'm talking about JS and PHP, but what LESS will do is take your `.less` file and turn it into a vanilla CSS file, either on the client (JS), or on your server (PHP).

Comment: How will LESS create a style sheet that can dynamically add a relative and an absolute width and return a pixel value? I don't see it.

Comment: My apologies... I thought he meant `100% + 20%`.

Comment: yeah, that won't work without JS (or a nifty trick like @dampe shows). But thanks for pointing out LessPHP, looks interesting!

Comment: LESS is beautiful; all those annoying little niggles you have with CSS all gone!